# wxWidgets: How to find what translations are currently available for the application?

Tags: wxwidgets

The application should offer switching the human language (the translation) via its menu. Unlike in the `internat` sample, the list of available languages should be created dynamically -- based on what translations are available. Is there any function to get the information?

The wanted behaviour is to reflect the situation when someone else adds the `.mo` catalog for another language, then the user can choose the language from the menu.

Thanks for your time and experience,

Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to get all the available catalogs now. It could be nice to add this to `wxTranslations` but for the moment it's not there.

Notice also that switching the language from a menu, as is done in many Windows programs, doesn't work really well with gettext approach neither as you need to recreate your entire UI to reflect the change in the language. This is why the language is usually only selected on the application launch anyhow.

Comment: I have found the `wxArrayString wxTranslations::GetAvailableTranslations(const wxString & domain) const`. It seems to be related to the problem, or not? (I am aware of the need to rebuild GUI after the language was changed.)

Comment: +1. Is there any overview of how `wxLocale`, `wxTranslations`, `wxXLocale` and the like things work together?

Comment: I wonder what you guys mean by rebuilding or recreating the entire UI.  It sounds so arduous!  However, all this is needed is a set of routines that are called when the user changes the language and which in turn call SetLabel and the like on the widgets.  Its a bit tedious but straightforward and the result is fast and impressive.  I always let the user change the language from a menu or similar.

Comment: @ravenspoint: I understand your view, and I also understand what rebuilding GUI is. The truth is that (re)building GUI may sometimes be easier than fixing the existing texts. Think, for example, about menus. You should have a piece of code that builds the menu. Then why to fix the old menu structure when you can build the new one almost with no effort?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://wxwidgets.info/wxtranslation/) will help? wxTranslationHelper can display available catalogs.